# Is RJMCMC robust to overfitting?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, overfitting

I have noticed that RJMCMC is often described as robust to overfitting. 
I am struggeling a bit with the intuition for this.
Why doesn't the Reversible jump Markov Chain Monte Carlo (RJMCMC) always get stuck at more complex models? Won't transdimensional jumps to models that have a higher dimensionality (more parameters) tend to be accepted more often, because they have a higher likelihood? 
Is the number of parameters penalized in some sense, is the procedure related to the Bayes factor?
The procedure is commonly used for model selection by using the number of iterations spent in each model as an estimate of the model evidence.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question came up in a seminar I attended this week and it was mentioned the Jacobian term in the acceptance probability will make those jumps to more complex models less likely, although I couldn't see why during the talk.  

Another handwavey response was that in higher dimensions the prior mass is "distributed more thinly" across more parameters and this makes it less likely to move.  

Hoping that some more detail (further reading perhaps?)  can be added to the answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first general comment is that RJMCMC is a *simulation method* attempting to produce simulations from a given posterior. As such it does not over- or under-fit. If anything, it converges to the posterior or it does not [in practice]. The over-fitting issue is concerning the posterior itself.

The robustness attribute on the posterior is the same as with the Bayes factor: larger parameter spaces get penalised [with a penalty in $n\log(p)$] in a natural manner [the Ockham's razor argument] when integrating the likelihood over a prior on that parameter space. A quick explanation when looking at the approximation produced by a RJMCMC algorithm is that the associated jumps between spaces [and thus models] are somewhat blind and unlikely to reach good overfitting values in larger dimensions. Much more likely to hit a poor fit value that will be rejected. Posteriors tend to get more concentrated when the dimension increases.